# How to extract a fixed number of characters before a string in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a text that contains somewhere in the document a citation to a court case, such as

```
x <- "2009 U.S. LEXIS"
```

I know it is always a four-digit year plus a space in front of the pattern "U.S. LEXIS". How should I extract these four digits of years?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to first search for this citation and then extract the year?

Comment: yes, exactly. I did not communicate clearly in the first place. This whole citation is buried in a long document and I need to locate it first. Preferably I can extract the whole thing in one effort. The whole citation is like "1947 U.S. LEXIS 2905". It always follows a ";" and precedes  a "*". There might not always be four digit after "LEXIS"

Comment: So please give us some sample data/text or at least please tell whether this all data/text has been parsed into columns/rows?

Comment: Try the method proposed by me.

Comment: Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the data/vector given by you was inadequate to let the experts here solve your problem.

**UPDATE** try this

```
str_extract_all(x, "\\d{4}(?=\\sU.S.\\sLEXIS)")

[[1]]
[1] "2009" "2015" "1990"
```

**OR** to extract these as numbers

```
lapply(str_extract_all(x, "\\d{4}(?=\\sU.S.\\sLEXIS)"), as.numeric)

[[1]]
[1] 2009 2015 1990
```

**OLD ANSWER** Moreover, I am also new in `regex` therefore my solution may not be a very clean method.  Typically your case is of searching nested groups in `regex` patterns.  Still, you can try this method

```
x <- "aabv 2009 U.S. LEXIS abcs aa 2015 U.S. LEXIS 45 fghhg ds fdavfd 1990 U.S. LEXIS bye bye!"

> x
[1] "aabv 2009 U.S. LEXIS abcs aa 2015 U.S. LEXIS 45 fghhg ds fdavfd 1990 U.S. LEXIS bye bye!"
```

Now follow these steps

```
library(stringr)
lapply(str_extract_all(x, "(\\d{4})\\sU.S.\\sLEXIS"), str_extract, pattern = "(\\d{4})")

[[1]]
[1] "2009" "2015" "1990"
```

Typically `"((\\d{4})\\sU.S.\\sLEXIS)"` would have worked as regex pattern but I am sure about nested groups in R, so used lapply here.  Basically `str_extract_all(x, "(\\d{4})\\sU.S.\\sLEXIS"` will cause to return all citations.  Try this.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.  Please accept the answer and upvote if it served the purpose as usually desired on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
x <- "2009 U.S. LEXIS"
as.numeric(sub('.*?(\\d{4}) U.S. LEXIS', '\\1', x))
#[1] 2009
```

Using `stringr::str_extract` :

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(x, '\\d{4}(?= U.S. LEXIS)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(x)
#[1] 2009
```

#### data

```
x <- "2009 U.S. LEXIS"
```

Answer (score 0):

substr function in stringr library solve it

```
substr(x,1,4)
```

if you need to convert in numeric, then you can return it as.numeric

```
as.numeric(substr(x,1,4))
```